# amp-story-player in a popup doesn't load the video

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-story

I embedded an amp-story in a webpage with the amp-story-player and it worked perfectly... until I moved it into a popup modal box. Since then the video isn't loading when the modal is displayed. (Initially the modal is in `display: none;` state, and after clicking a button it becomes `display: flex;`.)

However if I resize the browser window, the video suddenly starts playing.

How could I tell the player to start playing the story when the modal is shown?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

If the `amp-story-player` is added to the DOM only when the modal is displayed (for example with the createElement and appendChild JavaScript methods, or appended to the innerHTML content of the modal), then this problem isn't present

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).